# How does jQuery slideUp/Down/Toggle work?

Tags: jquery, css

I had assumed it animated the height of an element changing to and fro 0, but this is not the case. It seems to be toggling `display:block/none`, but I'm not sure how they're achieving the effect.

I ask because I want to be able to stop a sliding animation partway and replace the partially hidden element with something else and then slide it back into view, almost like a magic trick. But I can't replace it with something else without glitching unless I give the replacement the same mid-animation dimensions, and since `height` isn't what's changing, I'm at a loss.

Comment: im pretty sure slideUp / slideDown queries the `.height()`, assigns that value + `overflow:hidden` to the inline style, then animates the value of the height, and once it reaches 0 it calls back to add `display:none;`.

Comment: My further experiments confirm your thesis...I don't know what my original code is doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

there is a progress option that can be given to the even so that you can peform an action before the end

progress
Type: Function( Promise animation, Number progress, Number remainingMs )
A function to be called after each step of the animation, only once per animated element regardless of the number of animated properties. (version added: 1.8)

Check out [jquery toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)